# Trouble Installing/Opening Mix IDE on OS X

Tags: mix, installation, mac-osx

I am trying to install and use the Mix IDE.  I have downloaded the disk image from the github page (https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/releases/tag/v1.2.3).  There appears to be no issue when I download the .dmg or move it into my Applications folder.  However, when I try to open Mix (or AlethOne or AlethZero for that matter), I get a message that "Mix quit unexpectedly." I have tried installing a previous version of Mix, but I got the same result.

Are there any dependencies I need to install before hand? Or some other concern I should be aware of?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am running OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite) on a MacBook Pro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HOW TO INSTALL ETHEREUM UTILITIES ON MAC OSX**

1. Install Brew

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

2. Run `brew doctor`
3. Install the caktux formulae for Ethereum

`brew tap ethereum/ethereum`

4. `brew install cpp-ethereum --devel --with-gui --successful`
5. `brew linkapps cpp-ethereum`

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I completed the steps you described and got messages that ethereum was already installed.  I re-downloaded Mix, AlethZero and AlethOne from the github, as I didn't know how to start the application otherwise - and I got the same issue as before.  Is there a different step I should take to start the application?  Or perhaps do I need to do a more thorough uninstall first?  Thank you again

Comment: Try to uninstall first and then install :)

Comment: Thank you again - I haven't forgotten about your response/to accept, I'm still working through getting it to work though, I've run into a bunch of issues getting  the brew install to work, so working my way through all the forum posts I can find on each issue in succession

Comment: Finally got it!  I kept getting errors when running those commands above, and tried a few things to resolve them - installing libjson-rpc, and the last blocker was that I needed to update my XCode, which updated the version of clang on my machine.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Worth mentioning as well that for those living on the cutting edge and using the develop ppa of cpp-ethereum: Mix will no longer be installable by apt-get install mix - to avoid a naming conflict with the build tool of elixir that is also named mix, we renamed mix to mix-ide, so to install it, use

`apt-get install mix-ide`

instead of mix.

See - https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4e9wv1/ubuntu_develop_mix_renamed_to_mixide/